# Return blob from azure blob storage without saving it

Tags: python, azure, bottle

I am trying to get the blob from Azure blob storage and return the files to the user for download.

Now what I am trying to do is to get the file from azure, save it locally, and return the file as using Static file:

```
   def getDownload(filename):
        try:
            file = blob.get_blob('picture', filename)
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write(file)
        except:
            abort(400, 'Download blob fail')
        return static_file(filename, root='.', download=filename)
```

What I am trying to do it to stream it to user without first saving the file in the server.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need it to be routed through your server before delivering it to the end user?

Comment: Verification, limited people can download the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have any python sample code, but here is what you can do for verification purposes:

1. Make sure the container is not publicly accessible
2. Client sends a request to your web application for a given file inside the blob to your web application
3. Verify if this client is allowed to access that blob (return a 401 error, if not)
4. Create a Shared Access Signature for this blob for a short timeframe (approx. 5 mins should do)
5. Return a 303 (see other) html status code to the client containing the url to the blob in the Location-Header

Example:

Client requests http://myservice.cloudapp.net/blobs/somefile.ext and is verified to access the resource. Then he will be redirected to http://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/container/somefile.ext?SHARED_ACCESS_SIGNATURE. This link is only available to that client for a few minutes.

Comment: 4.Create a Shared Access Signature for this blob for a short timeframe (approx. 5 mins should do).... What if the download take longer time to complete?

Comment: Once initiated the download continues. But the download can only be started within the given timeframe.

Comment: are you sure about that @Nico ?

Comment: Actually I used to be sure about that. Here's a quote from Steve Marx in the Azure Forums (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/e8e76ca1-8f26-4096-ae3a-d169b354f4a6) stating that a download would complete if it was initiated during the validity of the Access Signature. There might be scenarios where it would not continue like multiple http-requests to download a file or a retry of a failed download...